# Best motherboard for simulations and AI's

Tags: motherboard

I am creating a semi-compact computer desk with a computer built into it. Although I have many questions about this subject, I believe it is best to start with the motherboard. The computer will be running simulations and very large programs, and a want smoothness and quick processing. I also want it to run in Linux, in case that changes anything. the best recommendation I have been given is the [GIGABYTE Z370](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813145035&cm_re=gigabyte_z370_aorus_gaming_5-_-13-145-035-_-Product), but I wanted to check in with the experts before I make this final, since gaming requires different specs than what I am looking for.

Update 2018-03-30: I realized that "AI's and simulations" is very vague; I would opt towards mostly GPU based programs, so running multiple scenarios and branched AI's. I hope this clears up the question.

Comment: What kind of simulations is this computer going to be running? Are the AI, for example, configured to run "scenario branches" in parallel (which would make a multi-core processor more useful)?

Comment: This kind of comes down to whether you will be running most of your processing on a GPU (Ex. Artificial Intelligence) or CPU (Ex. More traditional simulations). If you will be processing mainly on a GPU, you will want a Motherboard with as many Physical PCIe x16 slots, to add more GPUs as needed. If you are processing mainly on a CPU, you will want to invest in a higher end socket (X299, TR4, Even a Dual Socket board) to maximize performance.